# HTML5 date input - support partial ISO8601 strings?

Tags: html, date, validation, iso8601

I have an HTML5 date picker `<input type="date">`

I want people to be able to submit dates in any of these formats:

- YYYY-MM-DD
- YYYY-MM
- YYYY

That is, if they know the full date, they can submit that. If not, just a partial date is fine. This is allowed in [ISO8601 parsing rules for reduced accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Calendar_dates).

At the moment, if the input is partial - like "2020-04" - Firefox treats it as null and doesn't submit anything. Chrome shows a validation error.

[image]

[Date input does not accept the pattern attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Handling_browser_support) - so I can't use that.

Is there any way to tell the browser that a partial timestamp is allowed?

Comment: Did you find anything useful for this Terence?

Comment: @Codemonkey I didn't find a way to do this. Sorry.

Comment: No problem, I've written a kludge since it's only for my use in my admin system.  A checkbox next to the date field.  If I click it it toggles the type from date to text.  Does the job.